# Removing wires from "standard" electrical switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Unlike other switches where the user or contractor has installed by pushing in the wires, it has no small "clips" to push underneath the wire on the switch to remove them.  I finally just cut the wires but would still like to find a way to remove those wires from the switch.  You assistance appreciated.

OH, not that it matters, but it is a 3-way switch.

[image]

Comment: Usually use a very small screwdriver to push down beside wire.  Most people on here find them to be troublesome and recommend only using the screws to attach wires.

Comment: Exactly, but point is that this switch doesn't have that capability.

Comment: once you remove the wire from a backstab, the spring is sprung and will not hold reliably in the future.

Comment: Post your edit as an answer and I'll give ti a +1

Comment: This is what happens when you buy cheap outlets at an outlet store.   (Did I really just do that?).

Comment: If you had enough wire remaining, might be able to pull it out with a pair of pliers.  Takes some force.

Comment: @crip659 that's just a disaster waiting to happen. The next guy will use it, it'll arc internally and burn. Just throw it out.

Answer (score 3):

The manufacturer did not intend for the push terminals to be reused per photograph.   I replaced with Lutron 3 way switch and with a Leviton 3-way dimmer switch for the other switch.  The prior owner had switched the common and a traveler wire, which was why I bothered to examine in the first place.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to replace it with a better, spec or commercial grade device. Those will have proper backwire terminals that close and open by tightening the screw rather than a spring.

The differences between cheap residential and better grade devices are many and significant. There are plenty of youtube videos that show wiring devices cut open to expose the differences between them, so check them out if you are curious. Spec or commercial grade usually offers a good balance better features and construction vs. price.

The presence of spring-type backwire terminals indicates a low grade device. In other words, you were planning to re-use a device worth a dollar or two, maybe less. Many electricians recommend against using the spring-type backwire openings in the first place (referred to as "backstabbers").